# get height of oval drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to get height of oval drawn on canvas.Below is my code to draw oval on canvas.

```
      function drawOval(startX, startY, endX, endY, strokeColor) {
    x = endX;
    y = endY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    context.moveTo(startX, startY + (y - startY) / 2);
    context.bezierCurveTo(startX, startY, x, startY, x, startY + (y - startY) / 2);
    context.bezierCurveTo(x, y, startX, y, startX, startY + (y - startY) / 2);
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = strokeColor;
    context.fill();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest drawing the oval in a different way:

- Bezier is more complex and performance hungry
- Bezier does not draw an accurate oval (ellipse)
- More difficult to extract certain points for measure without using a manual formula.

To use a different approach which is signature compatible with what you have you could do:

```
function drawOval(startX, startY, endX, endY, strokeColor) {

    var rx = (endX - startX) * 0.5,  // get radius for x 
        ry = (endY - startY) * 0.5,  // get radius for y
        cx = startX + rx,            // get center position for ellipse
        cy = startY + ry,
        a = 0,                       // current angle
        step = 0.01,                 // angle step
        pi2 = Math.PI * 2;

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    context.moveTo(cx + rx, cy);     // initial point at 0 deg.

    for(; a < pi2; a += step)
        context.lineTo(cx + rx * Math.cos(a), // create ellipse path
                       cy + ry * Math.sin(a));

    context.closePath();             // close for stroke

    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = strokeColor;
    context.fill();
}
```

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/MEmh8/)**

Now you will get height (and width) simply by doing:

```
var width = Math.abs(endX - startX),
    height = Math.abs(endY - startY);
```